# How to get Swagger UI to use my titles?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-php

I am using Swagger-php and Swagger-UI and it all works just fine but for one annoyance. The UI that Swagger-UI creates has the expected click-to-expand sections for my API routes, but the title of each one appears to be the JSON file generated and not any name I can give it. After the title, the description is the one I give in my annotation, but the title I seem to have no control over.

So if I have routes that begin with a resourcePath of /foo, and a description that says "Foo API Functions," the UI looks like:

foo.json : Foo API Functions

I don't want "foo.json" I'd much rather specify what this says. Like just "Foo" or even "Foo Functions" and then change my description to something more meaningful like, "This is where you find the foo functions."

Am I missing which annotation to use for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you manually edit the api-docs.json file. You can replace the .json with .{format} and all will display correctly and function correctly. Not sure why the .{format} is not inserted by default. Slightly annoying.

Comment: Manually editing the file after every build? Seriously?

Comment: Well that's the only solution I could find. I know it's quite annoying. I'm also looking for a better solution. If you do come across one please share it.

Comment: Just a note that I've not found any solution yet :-(

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into this problem, but I couldn't find anything on either the`swagger-php` or `swagger-ui` github pages mentioning this. So, I wrote a short build script (assuming a Unix-like OS) as a work around, which will first build all the docs using `swagger.phar` and then run `sed` to do an inline string replace on the problematic string. Here is what I did below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# write API documentation from "src" directory to the "docs" directory
/usr/bin/php swagger.phar src -o docs

# replace instances of "json" with "{format}" to fix swagger-php formatting issue
sed -i -e 's/json/{format}/g' docs/api-docs.json
```

Comment: I was doing something similar to yourself, but I recently notice the issue has been fixed: https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/commit/25c57483805a0bdf50af004707106fcb7e6f8dcb

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed in swagger-php 0.9.1**

I don't know why swagger-ui strips out `".{format}"` but not `".json"`

The `.{format}` was not inserted by default because it might be confusing. It suggests the presence of different formats and swagger-php only supports the json format.